# Facebook - embed latest posts from different users

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am building a community site and for each user's profile page (which can be viewed by any site visitor), I need to embed their latest posts from Facebook. All the examples I have seen don't cover this scenario in that a FB login seems to be required.

Thus the profile rendering script needs to be able to request the latest posts from any community member's FB profile. Can this be done without requiring logins etc.

Any pointers will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a Javascript SDK or PHP SDK as an API? In either case, you would need to ask for a permission. Then you can use the Javascript API like this.

```
FB.api(
    "/me/feed",
    function (response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
        /* handle the result */
      }
    }
);
```

The response object normally have an array of posts that you can embed in your website. For using this, you app needs to have the following permission,

```
user_posts
```

Comment: Thanks Ashif for your response - so each community user would have to grant the 'user_posts' permission to my app - this unfortunately makes the desired concept unworkable I think...

Comment: Actually the app is nothing but another website itself, loaded into the iframe of the facebook canvas. That's  facebook app. If you have to pull posts from your users, then what you have to do would be as follows.

1. Ask for permission at the beginning.
2. Read the user feed in scheduled intervals of time. (In case user makes another post)

I have already implemented something like this.
If you find my answer useful, please provide a vote. That helps.